# how to set columns of pandas dataframe as list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

[image]I have a pandas dataframe and when I try to acess its columns (like `df[["a"]`) it is not possible because 
the columns are defined as an "Index" object (`pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`).  or `Index(['col2','col2'], [![enter image description here][1]][1]dtype='object')`

I tried convert it doing something like  `df.columns = df.columns.tolist()`  and also `df.columns = [str(col) for col in df.columns]`
but the columns remained as an Index object.

What I want is to make `df.columns` and it would return a list object.

What Can I do ?

Comment: Could you post some example of your dataframe, like print out, or code to recreate it

Comment: I've put a print of my dataframe and the columns list resultant

Comment: `df.columns` is **always** an Index/MultiIndex series, no matter what you assign. If you want a list from it, `tolist` as you did, or `list(df.columns)` are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`columns` is not callable.  So, you need to remove the parenthesis `()`:

`df.columns` will give you the name of the columns as an object.

`list(df.columns)` will give you the name of the columns as a list.

In your example, `list(ss.columns)` will return a list of column names.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df.columns.values.tolist()
```

since you were trying to convert it using this approach, you missed the `values` attribute

Comment: Indeed, it would return me a list. However, doent alter the dataframe , since if I try the comand  df.columns again, it would still return the Index object.What I wanted was to alter the dataframe like an "inplace = True"

Comment: @lucas862 ithink you are looking for `df.rename` which will allow you to rename your columns right? `df.rename (columns={oldname: newname}, inplace = true}`

Answer (score 0):

#### You have to wrap it over list Constructor to function it like a list i.e list(ss.columns).

```
list(ss.columns)
```

Hope this works!